# bundle install rails error `parse': Illformed requirement [""] (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ran bundle install

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/Users/judyngai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:90:in `parse': Illformed requirement [""] (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
```

what is the problem with my bundler?

is working in a blank app but just not at the app that I am working on.

thank you

here is my gemfile as requested

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

#High Voltage
gem "high_voltage", "~> 1.2.4"

#Database 
gem "pg", "~> 0.16.0"

#to make attribute accessible work 
gem "protected_attributes", "~> 1.0.3"

#Authentication , upgrading devise?
gem "devise", "~> 3.0.3"

#Active Admin 
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'            

#Simple Form
gem 'simple_form'

#js runting for bootstrap to work 
gem "therubyracer"

#Web Server 
gem "thin"

#Student Picture Uploaders 
gem "rmagick"
gem "carrierwave"

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I don't see any syntax errors in my gemfile. I remember seeing the same error before and removed an extra comma from my gemfile.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Gemfile`? Also did you check the Bundler troubleshooting documentation?

Comment: @user2062950 Hi I posted my gemfile, and no I haven't check the doc but I can use bundle install no problem on a blank app. I think there is something wrong with my app.

Comment: It could be a problem with the gems in your bundle. Have you tried removing them one by one until the problem goes away?

Comment: I managed to bundle install okay with that Gemfile (with pg and rmagick commented out - sorry not going to install those dependencies). That was with bundler version 1.3.5. That suggests it might be environmental rather than a problem with your Gemfile specifically.

Comment: @Shadwell I did what you said, I uncommented out each gem one by one and managed to got it to work again.